# Higher dimensional generalization of a proposition on Riemann surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

We have the following proposition:

> PROPOSITION. Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface with a volume form $\omega$ and $u: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function s.t. $\displaystyle \int_X u \;\omega=0$ and $u \not\equiv 0$. Let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. There exists $s \in H^0(X,L^n)$ for large $n$ s.t. $u(s)=\sum_{P \in \operatorname{div}(s)} u(P)>0$.

LEMMA. For every $P_0 \in X$ and every open subset $U \subseteq X$, there exists $Q_1,\dots,Q_n \subseteq X$ s.t. $\sum Q_i \sim nP_0$. Here "$\sim$" means linear equivalence for divisors.

PROOF OF LEMMA. $\operatorname{Sym}^k(X) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Jac}(X)$, $\sum P_i \longmapsto \sum P_i -kP_0$ is projective bundle for large $k$, in particular it is an open map. Thus image of $\operatorname{Sym}^k(U)$ is open and meet some torsion point (since the set of torsion points is dense), which means that we have a torsion point $\sum P_i - kP_0 \in \operatorname{Jac}(X)$. Then $m\sum P_i \sim kmP_0$.

The proposition follows immediately after the lemma.

---

Now I wonder if we can generalize this to higher dimensional cases:

> PROPOSITION. Let $X$ be a projectve complex manifold with a volume form $\omega$ and $u: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function s.t. $\displaystyle \int_X u \;\omega=0$ and $u \not\equiv 0$. Let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. There exists $s \in H^0(X,L^n)$ for large $n$ s.t. $\displaystyle u(s)=\int_{\operatorname{div(s)}} u \; \omega|_{\operatorname{div}(s)}>0$.

The difference is, divisor now are not local (not points but a subvarieties, and is "global"). The local play we did in Riemann surface case is no longer available. And I'm kind of afraid of all those "generalizations of Jacobian" for higher dimensional complex varieties and I doubt if they help.

Any thoughts or comments are appreciated.

Comment: Hi, it seems to me that your claim is not properly stated. With your notations, $\omega$ is a $2n$-form, where $n$ is the dimension of $X$, and then when you define $u(s)$ as an integral of $u$ times the restriction of $\omega$ to the zero set of $s$, the integral being over the zero set of $s$. But if you have a $2n$-form, there is no natural way to define its restriction to a submanifold of codimension 1.